# How to use Challonge API in Google AppsScript

Tags: json, rest, google-apps-script

I am brand new to api calls and am trying to figure out how to use Google Sheets to interact with the [Challonge API](https://api.challonge.com/v1).  I apologize if this question sounds basic but I cannot seem to figure out how to make a call.  Every call I make returns a message that I have the wrong URL.  I have tried to follow the example of someone else on stackoverflow but I am unsuccessful.  I feel if I can get one working I will be able to take it from there.

I have tried a few URLs but I cannot seem to figure out how to format them correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

---

1. Getting a [list of my tournaments](https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/index)

```
api_key = "###"
getTournament_url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/index.json"
getTournamentPayload = {"api_key" : api_key, "state" : "all"};
getTournamentOptions = {"method" : "GET", "muteHttpExceptions" : true, "contentType": "application/json", "payload" : JSON.stringify(getTournamentPayload)};

function getRunningTournaments() {
  // Get a list of running tournaments from your account
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getTournament_url, getTournamentOptions);
Logger.log("");
Logger.log(response); 
}
```

---

2. [Creating a tournament](https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/create)

```
api_key = "###"
createTournament_url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/create.json"
createTournamentPayload = {"api_key" : api_key, "tournament_type" : "single elimination", "name": "Sample Tournament 1"};
createTournamentOptions = {"method" : "POST", "muteHttpExceptions" : true, "contentType": "application/json", "payload" : JSON.stringify(createTournamentPayload)};

function createTournament(){
  //Create a new tournament
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(createTournament_url, createTournamentOptions)
  Logger.log("")
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the response you're getting back? The answer will depend on what the error says, and the status code you're getting.

Comment: Good morning - I receive HTML code for a webpage as a reply.  The entire reply is too many characters for StackOverflow but here is the important part when running  getRunningTournaments function - thank you for your assistance:

</a>
          <a href="https://youtu.be/NDkuucSWVWw?t=1m6s" target="_blank">
            <h3>The page you're looking for isn't here.</h3>
          </a>
          <hr>
          You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
          If you know the name of the tournament you're looking for, you can <a href="/tournaments">search for it</a>.

Comment: What about a status code? Sounds like a 404 error to me. IE the web address you're trying to hit doesn't exist. Double and triple check for any typos in your code. Although https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/index.json is a valid endpoint...